# How can i split URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, split

For example:
google.com/en/game/game1.html
should be
google.com/index.php?p1=en&p2=game&p3=game1.html

how can i split URL and send index.php the part of "/" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only achieve this if the query parameters are of a fixed length. Otherwise there is an other way but requires parsing of the path in the application.

### Fixed length implementation

The following rule matches all three URL parts then rewrites them as named query arguments to **index.php**.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3
```

This rewrites:

```
/en/game/game1.html
```

To:

```
/index.php?p1=en&p2=game&p3=game1.html
```

### Unknown length implementation

```
# Don't rewrite if file exist. This is to prevent rewriting resources like images, scripts etc
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?path=$0
```

This rewrites:

```
/en/game/game1.html
```

To:

```
/index.php?path=en/game/game1.html
```

Then you can **parse** the path in the application.

---

**Edit:)** To make it so the rewrite rule only matches if the first level of the URL consists of two characters do:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/([^/]+)/(.+)$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3
```

You can also do it for the *unknown length* implementation so:

```
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z]{2}/ index.php?path=$0
```

Comment: And how can i be sure that the first part of URL "en/" is 2 char?
so all languages is be 2 letter and if the URL is 3 letter like "enw/"   rewrite shouldn't work?