# fake image url htaccess - add seo text

Tags: .htaccess

my image real url is
http://www.example.com/images/201712/2j80owr1sgg0co00k0.jpg

but I want to show image url as
http://www.example.com/images/201712/this-is-an-image-2j80owr1sgg0co00k0.jpg

I tried a lot of combinations but they did not work. Because I need last 1 part of url seperated by (-)
Thanks for help

Comment: Can you show us what  you have tried?

Comment: RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.jpg$ /images/$1/$2 [L,QSA,NC] 
and also I read this question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361561/how-can-i-split-url-with-htaccess
but I couldnt write code because my fake path length ins unknown.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(images/\d+/)[^/]+-(.+\.jpg)$ $1$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: still doesnot work.
also tried RewriteRule ^(images/\d+/)[^/]+-(.+\.jpg)$ images/$1/$2 [NC,L]