# How do I rewrite an URL to an PHP array using mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't figure out how to rewrite an URL (using mod_rewrite) from the following form

`https://example.com/foo/bar/123/asd/qwerty`

to the following form

`https://example.com/index.php?controller=foo&action=bar&params[]=123&params[]=asd&params[]=qwerty`

There will always be a controller and action supplied, but the number of parameters after that may vary. I'm currently passing the entire 123/asd/qwerty as a string to $_GET['params'] in PHP, but I would now like to turn this string into an already split array instead.

What RewriteRule do I use?

Comment: I Thing your answer are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361561/how-can-i-split-url-with-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that what you need is a rewrite rule. 
What mod_rewrite is doing, when applied is leading  from
**A:** https://example.com/foo/bar/123/asd/qwerty to 
**B:** https://example.com/index.php?controller=foo&action=bar&params[]=123&params[]=asd&params[]=qwerty

BUT : In the above case **B** is the original URL and **A** is the re-written one...which is just more user friendly. Since you do not pass a variable in URL you can not "GET" it something from it. I think the only way to do it is to grab the url and split it in parts using php